# Using resources of another project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

**Use-case**

1. A static lib with a collection of custom UI controls
2. PNGs for the custom UI are part of the static Lib project
3. Another executable project is linked against the static lib to use it's UI collections

**Problem**

It appears that the IDE doesn't ~know~ to automatically embed the resources ( eg. PNG files ) associated with the static lib.

- Is there any way to make these static Lib resources embedded in the main executable project other than directly adding them to the project ?
- is there any way for the IDE  to automatically detect the dependency and include the resources in the resulting executable ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to automatically copy resources from a static library into another target just by linking against that library (as you could with a framework).

The best workaround I've been able to find is to put the library's assets in a directory ending in ".bundle" (e.g., MyLibraryResources.bundle). Xcode (and Finder) will treat this directory as a single unit. Targets using the library will then only have to add a single resource, the bundle, to the project. It's not perfect, but it's pretty easy.

In your library, when referencing resources in the bundle, you would just do something like:

```
NSString *pathToSomeImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyLibraryResources.bundle/SomeImage.png" ofType:nil];
```

Bundles can be a bit of a pain to work with since Finder treats them differently than ordinary directories. You can make dealing with them easier by adding a target in the library project that assembles the bundle by copying in your resources.